Necessary and Sufficient Conditions to Obtain Power Law from Weighting of Exponential Functions?
What properties on probability distribution $p(x)$ are (1) sufficient and (2) necessary to make
$$-\log \Bigg(1 - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} p(x) \, (1-x)^k dx \Bigg)$$
result in a power law
$$\propto k^{-b}$$
for some constant $b > 0$?
I have an implicit assumption that the distribution $p(x)$ "nice" in some sense, but I'm not sure exactly what this assumption is. Perhaps smooth, continuous, something similar?
I've already derived that the Beta distribution and Kumaraswamy distribution are sufficient. Numerically, the continuous Bernoulli distribution works as well. I'm looking for what the general "structure" underlying these distributions is.
